# Retrieving SQL database value in dropdown with multiple select option and post the values

Tags: php, html

I have retrieved the database values in dropdown list with multiple select option using PHP MySQL. My code is as follows.

```
$sql = "SELECT student_id, name, phone FROM student";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    echo "<select name='num' multiple >";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       echo "<option value='" . "'>" . $row['name']. " " . $row['phone_number'] ."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";




} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

What I need is, I want to post the multiple selected phone_number values to another page. Also, Is it possible to create a checkbox before the list values?

[image: Now am getting the output as in this image.]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php multiple select drop down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623145/php-multiple-select-drop-down)

Comment: That seems to have manual array values. I need to retrieve the array values from sql..

Answer (score 0):

Change this line to :

```
echo "<select name='num[]' multiple >";
```

name should be in array format like `num[]` not like `num`

Comment: ok. Thanks for your reply. And how can post only the selected phone_number values to another form? Moreover, Am not getting checkbox before the name or number.

Comment: "And how can post only the selected phone_number values to another form? Moreover, Am not getting checkbox before the name or number." where is the code for that ? and you should post another question for this.

Comment: echo "<option value='" . "'>" . $row['name']. " " . $row['phone_number'] ."</option>"; In this I want to select a few names and only the selected phone_number corresponding to the names has to be passed into another form or page.